# symfony easyadmin dropzone field

Tags: symfony, dropzone, easyadmin, symfonyux

is there a way in symfony easyadmin I can configureFields of type symfony ux Dropzone ??

I used this method but when I drag drop, the preview image does not show ,any help

```
yield Field::new('imageFile')
->onlyOnForms()
->setFormType(DropzoneType::class);
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I'm starting to see more and more of these sf questions being abandoned.

Comment: no I didn't find any solution .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've figured out a way to achieve this;

1. you have to [register symfony-ux dropzone form theme within twig](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/namespaced_paths.html):

```
twig:
    paths: 
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/symfony/ux-dropzone/templates': CustomDropzoneNamespace
```

2. add the form theme when using the DropzoneType (or globally if you want):

```
yield Field::new('imageFile')
    ->setFormType(DropzoneType::class,)
    ->addFormTheme('@CustomDropzoneNamespace/form_theme.html.twig')
```

3. you have to make sure that the stimulux-ux is loaded properly within easyadmin:

```
public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return Assets::new()
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('backend');
    }
```

where "backend" is a webpack entry that loads [the stimulus js controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/ux.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines in your DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
Where 'app' is your webpack entry's name

```
    public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return parent::configureAssets()
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('app')
        ;
    }

    public function configureCrud(): Crud
    {
        return parent::configureCrud()
            ->addFormTheme('@Dropzone/form_theme.html.twig')
            ;
    }
```